# WPF c# ImageSource в Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, bitmap, imagesource

Не могли бы вы мне помочь сделать преобразовние из `ImageSource` в `Bitmap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно используется обратное преобразование. Но в целом:

```
  public static Bitmap BitmapSourceToBitmap2(BitmapSource srs)
    {
        int width = srs.PixelWidth;
        int height = srs.PixelHeight;
        int stride = width * ((srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height * stride);
            srs.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), ptr, height * stride, stride);
            using (var btm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, ptr))
            {
                return new Bitmap(btm);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }
```

Обратное:

```
 private ImageSource ImageSourceForBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            var handle = bmp.GetHbitmap();
            try
            {
                return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(handle);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо! А не могли бы показать что за обратные преоброзвавания?

Comment: Не работает, т.к. в перегрузке BitmapSource, а Image возвращает ImageSource

Comment: Обратное добавил в ответ.
А с преобразованием, 
var bitmapImage = Image.Image as BitmapImage;